# Pasar una prueba unitaria de vistas basadas en clases de Django

Tags: django, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy agregándole pruebas unitarias a mi blog y no puedo pasar la prueba *que debería pasar*.

La prueba es esta:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve
from apps.blog.views import EntryList

class ApiRootTest(TestCase):
    def test_la_portada_apunta_a_entrylist_view(self):
        found = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(found.func, EntryList.as_view())
```

Es muy simple, quiero probar que la raíz apunta a la CBV EntryList, que es mas o menos así:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from apps.blog.models import Entry

class EntryList(ListView):
    model = Entry
```

Y en el archivo `urls.py` la raíz apunta a esa clase:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', EntryList.as_view(), name='index')
    ]
```

Al ejecutar el este, obtengo este error:

```
 $ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_la_portada_apunta_a_entrylist_view (src.apps.blog.tests.ApiRootTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/datos/Proyectos/nspaces/src/apps/blog/tests.py", line 11, in test_la_portada_apunta_a_entrylist_view
    self.assertEqual(found.func, EntryList.as_view())
AssertionError: <function EntryList at 0x11010dd08> != <function EntryList at 0x10fe1dea0>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s
```

No entiendo porque se crean dos instancias de la clase `EntryList`, en lugar de una sola, lo que haría que mi prueba pasara Ok.

#### ¿Qué cambios debo hacer para pasar la prueba unitaria?

*Plus:* ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si observás bien lo que tu test unitario está devolviendo, te vas a dar cuenta que está comparando dos objetos de memoria distintos:

```
<function EntryList at 80x11010dd0> != <function EntryList at 0x10fe1dea0>
```

Porque 80x11010dd0 es distinto de 0x10fe1dea0.

Me parece que hay dos maneras de resolver tu problema. Uno, pero no es lo correcto, es usar el método `isinstance` que, en vez de comparar si la direccion de memoria es la misma, va a fijarse si los dos son instancias de la misma clase. Esto sería:
        self.assertEqual(isinstance(EntryList.as_view(), found.func))

Pero, en realidad, lo que vos querés probar en tu test es si se tu función se ha llamado, es decir, si se ha ejecutado cuando usas esa vista. Para esto está la biblioteca unittest y dentro de ella la función mock. Si "mockeas" tu función, mock te permite saber si tu función mockeada fue llamada (ejecutada) una vez o muchas. Esto se hace así:

```
def test_la_portada_apunta_a_entrylist_view(self):
        mocked_view = mock.patch('apps.blog.views.EntryList')
        found = resolve('/')
        self.assertTrue(mocked_view.called)
```

Podés ver más sobre mock en [mock tuto](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) y [documentación oficial de mock en python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)